# How to display template file in popup model in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, modal-popup

I want to show phtml file inside popup on click of a button but it shows by default open how to resolve it anyone has an idea ?? I want to open when I click on button

```
<div>
    <a href="#" id="click-me">Notify Me</a>
</div>

<div id="popup-mpdal">
                <?php include ($block->getTemplateFile(Vendor_Module::notifyoutofstcoks.phtml')) ?>
</div>

  <script>
require(
    [
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
    ],
  function(
        $,
        modal
    ) {
        var options = {
            type: 'popup',
            responsive: true,
            innerScroll: true,
            buttons: [{
                text: $.mage.__('Continue'),
                class: '',
                click: function () {
                    this.closeModal();
                }
            }]
        };

        var popup = modal(options, $('#popup-mpdal'));
        $("#click-me").on('click',function(){
            $("#popup-mpdal").modal("openModal");
        });

    }
);
</script>
```

Comment: Follow this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43061703/magento2-how-to-show-phtml-file-in-a-popup?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Try using this code to call phtml within another phtml file

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template")->setTemplate("Vendor_Module::notifyoutofstcoks.phtml")->toHtml(); ?>
```

To open modal on link click follow devdocs tutorial
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_modal.html

Comment: but how to show popup on click of the link ??                                                            
 using this its shows by default whole phtml file

Comment: Updated my answer. Follow devdocs tutoral to use modal in order to show dialog box on link click

Comment: thank you it's working fine

Comment: Please mark answer as correct, so that your post is set to resolved and it would be helpful for others in future